Auto Retry in Firebase Transaction
I encountered an issue when using Promise for multiple transactions with the purpose of asynchronously deleting data for multiple users simultaneously.
I'm implementing the code like this:
await Promise.allSettled(
  membersList.map(async (memberData) => {
    try {
      await firestore().runTransaction(async (ts) => {
        logger.log("Start Handle Delete Member Data: "+ memberData.id)
        await handleDeleteMemberData(
          site,
          memberData.id,
          ts
        );
      });
    } catch {
  }}))

async function handleDeleteMemberData(...) {
  async function handleDeleteMemberData(
  site: SITE,
  deleteMemberId: string,
  ts: Transaction
) {
  //Get Data
  const memberPointInformation = await getMemberPointWithTransaction(
    site,
    deleteMemberId,
    ts
  );
  const memberRankTemporys =
    await getMemberRankTemporaryByMemberIdWithTransaction(
      site,
      deleteMemberId,
      ts
    );
  const companyMembers = await getMemberCompanyWithTransaction(
    site,
    deleteMemberId,
    ts
  );
  const members = await getMemberByIdWithTransaction(site, deleteMemberId, ts);


  //Update Data
  await deleteMemberPoint(
    site,
    deleteMemberId,
    memberPointInformation,
    ts
  );
  await deleteMemberRankTemporaryHistory(
    site,
    memberRankTemporys,
    logsBuffer,
    ts
  );
  await deleteCompanyMember(site, companyMembers, ts);
  await deleteMember(site, members, ts);

  // Call Third-party Service
  await deleteFirebaseAuthentication(deleteMemberId);

  logger.log("End Handle Delete Member Data: "+ memberData.id)
}

And all function call firestore to get data
function getMemberPointWithTransaction(
  site: string,
  memberId: string,
  trans: Transaction
): Promise<any> {
  return trans.get(firestore().collection(getPath(site)).doc(memberId));
}

async function getMemberCompanyWithTransaction(
  site: SITE,
  memberId: string,
  ts: Transaction
) {
  return ts
    .get(
      firestore()
        .collection(getPath(site))
        .where(COLLECTION_COMPANY_MEMBERS.MEMBER_ID, "==", memberId)
        .where(COLLECTION_COMPANY_MEMBERS.DELETED_AT, "==", null)
    )
    .then((querySnap) => {
      const result = querySnap.docs.map((doc) => {
        return { id: doc.id };
      });
      if (result.length > 0) {
        return result;
      } else {
        return [];
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      return [];
    });
}
async function getMemberByIdWithTransaction(
  site: SITE,
  memberId: string,
  ts: Transaction
) {
  return ts
    .get(
      firestore()
        .collection(getPath(site))
        .where(firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), "==", memberId)
        .where(COLLECTION_MEMBERS.DELETED_AT, "==", null)
    )
    .then((querySnap) => {
      const result = querySnap.docs.map((doc) => {
        return { id: doc.id, monoful_authen_id: doc.data().monoful_authen_id };
      });
      if (result) {
        return result;
      } else {
        return [];
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      return [];
    });
}

Code for update data
async function deleteMemberPoint(
  site: SITE,
  deleteMemberId: string,
  memberPointInformation: any,
  ts: Transaction
) {
  try {
    await updateMemberPointById(
      site,
      deleteMemberId,
      {
        usable_point: 0,
        point_expiration_date: null,
      },
      ts
    );
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(
      `Member ${deleteMemberId} has not member_point_informations document`
    );
  }
}

async function deleteMemberRankTemporaryHistory(
  site: SITE,
  memberRankTemporys: any[],
  ts: Transaction
) {
  await Promise.all(
    memberRankTemporys.map(async (memberRankTempory: any) => {
      try {
        updateMemberRankTemporaryWithTransaction(
          site,
          memberRankTempory.id,
          {
            deleted_at: getCurrentTimestamp(),
          },
          ts
        );
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(
          `${new Date().toISOString()}: Delete member_ranks_temporary_histories [${
            memberRankTempory.id
          }] error.\n${JSON.stringify(error)}`
        );
      }
    })
  );
}

function updateCompanyMemberWithTransaction(
  site: string,
  docId: string,
  data: any,
  ts: Transaction
) {
  return ts.update(
    firebaseHelper.firestore.getCollection(getPath(site)).doc(docId),
    addTimeUpdate(data)
  );
}

async function deleteCompanyMember(
  site: SITE,
  companyMembers: any[],
  ts: Transaction
) {
  await Promise.all(
    companyMembers.map(async (companyMember: any) => {
      try {
        updateCompanyMemberWithTransaction(
          site,
          companyMember.id,
          {
            deleted_at: getCurrentTimestamp(),
            deleted_by: "",
          },
          ts
        );
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(
          `${new Date().toISOString()}: Delete company_members [${
            companyMember.id
          }] error.${JSON.stringify(error)}\n`
        );
      }
    })
  );
}

function updateCompanyMemberWithTransaction(
  site: string,
  docId: string,
  data: any,
  ts: Transaction
) {
  return ts.update(
    firebaseHelper.firestore.getCollection(getPath(site)).doc(docId),
    addTimeUpdate(data)
  );
}

async function deleteMember(
  site: SITE,
  members: any[],
  ts: Transaction
) {
  await Promise.all(
    members.map(async (member: any) => {
      try {
        await updateMemberWithTransaction(
          site,
          member.id,
          {
            deleted_at: getCurrentTimestamp(),
            deleted_by: "",
          },
          ts
        );
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(
          `${new Date().toISOString()}: Delete member [${
            member.id
          }] error.\n${JSON.stringify(error)}`
        );
      }
    })
  );
}

async function updateMemberWithTransaction(
  site: string,
  docId: string,
  data: any,
  trans: Transaction
) {
  trans.update(firestore().collection(getPath(site)).doc(docId), data);
}

async function deleteFirebaseAuthentication(
  deleteMemberId: string
) {
  try {
    await firebaseHelper.deleteUser(deleteMemberId);
    );
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(
      `${new Date().toISOString()}: Delete firebase authentication [${deleteMemberId}] error.\n${JSON.stringify(
        error
      )}`
    );
  }
}

For some reason, the update operation is retried from the second transaction onwards, after the first transaction succeeds.
The log looks like this:
Start Handle Delete Member Data: 1
Start Handle Delete Member Data: 2
End Handle Delete Member Data: 1
End Handle Delete Member Data: 2
Start Handle Delete Member Data: 2
Error

This causes an error because the delete call to the third-party service was already executed in the first attempt. The second retry will raise an error.
I checked the documentation, and Firebase mentioned that if data being fetched within a transaction is modified, it will automatically be retried <This is document>. However, based on my system checks, each transaction is performed independently for each user. Therefore, each transaction should only affect the data related to that particular user and not interfere with other documents.
Have you ever encountered this issue? If so, could you please provide some guidance on how to investigate it? Thank you very much.
My logs https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CdNC3HqHB3vkGaiVtNE8N-B4H_jtwugg/view?usp=sharing

You've removed all the important details about what your transaction is doing in handleDeleteMemberData. We have no idea what it's actually doing, and what it might be doing wrong. Also, you should definitely never make API calls to another service during a transaction.  Transactions should be fast and stateless and operate only on the database documents and use local memory for reading only.

@DougStevenson I need to conceal certain information within the function because it pertains to a project and requires confidentiality. However, I can ensure that for each transaction that only updates the 'delete_at' field for the correct documents based on member_id. It might seem illogical, but is there a possibility that if transaction 1 submits and changes the document for member_1 in the member collection, transaction 2 fetching the document for member_2 from the member collection would be considered as altering data (even though the document for member_2 remains unchanged

Additionally, retries don't occur frequently despite the test data being similar. To increase the likelihood of reproducing the error, I've debugged and intentionally delayed the update process in the second transaction by 1 to 2 seconds compared to the first transaction. By doing so, the error recurrence rate is 100%.

On Stack Overflow, you should provide a complete minimal reproducible example so that everyone can be in agreement about what the code actually does. Without that, we are just guessing what the problem might be without any facts to back it up.

Yes, I will update code

I updated my code and I was deleted some part not important. Thank for your support @DougStevenson

You really shouldn't use deleteFirebaseAuthentication inside a transaction.  That is likely to increase the probability of performance or other problems. A transaction should only work with document data.

Also, it's generally not a good idea to mix async/await with then/catch callbacks.  Use one or the other, but not both. Your code will make a lot more sense if you just stick to async/await.

yes, thank for suggest,  but I still want to understand why retries behave unusually like that.

We can't see the documents that are actually being modified by this transaction. The fact that it's being retried suggests that there is some overlap.  Why don't you log all of the documents being written and look for that overlap?  That's not something we can do for you.  I strongly doubt that the transaction is being retried for no other reason.

I pushed my logs, can you check for me. Thank you so much @DougStevenson

So if a transaction is getting document data from one collection A, and the previous transaction modifies any document in collection A, then Firebase will still consider it overlapping data and will retry the transaction. With my data processing scenario as described, when one transaction commits successfully, subsequent transactions will retry. 1 (done) --> 2, 3 retry; 2 (done) -> 3 retry. In this case, sequential data updates would be better than asynchronous, right?"

If you want to know what's better, you should observe and benchmark your options.  You pick the one with better performance characteristics.
